# Get PropertyInfo[] from a class, leaving out indexer method

Tags: c#, class, properties

I have an indexer method inside a class that allows me to do this:

```
var foo = Class["bar"];
Class["bar"] = foo;
```

Here it is:

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
    set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
}
```

I want to get an array of PropertyInfo[] and loop through it to get the values of the properties.  But this extension method (type System.Object) is making its way in the array and I don't know how to exclude it.

I could exclude it inside my loop.  But it could be problematic if my class **does** contain an "Item" property.  Any ideas?

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Class).GetProperties();
foreach(var prop in properties)
    if(prop.name == "Item")
        continue;
```

[image]

Comment: What extension method?  Extension methods are static _methods_, not _properties_.

Comment: "Extension property" then?

Comment: That's an indexer, not an extension method.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK C# does not support extension properties, only methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine if a property is an indexer by using the [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) method:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Class).GetProperties();
foreach(var prop in properties)
    if(prop.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)  // it is an indexer
        continue;
```

If the method returns a non-empty array then it is an indexer.  That way you don't have to rely on the default name of `Item` that the compiler generates unless overridden by an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of [IndexParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) and, if more than 0, exclude it.

```
foreach(var prop in typeof(Class).GetProperties()
    .Where (x => x.GetIndexParameters().Length <= 0))
{        
    if(prop.name == "Item")
        continue;
}
```